# log with log4j from jsf web apllication

Tags: jsf, logging, log4j, glassfish-3

i have been trying to log to a text file with log4j from a simple jsf web application, but no success. Every time i open the file at location, nothing was written to it. I am deploying with glassfish. Below is my log4j.properties configuration

```
log4j.rootLogger = debug, stdout, FILE

log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target = System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.FILE = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.maxFileSize = 100kb
log4j.appender.FILE.maxBackupIndex = 2
log4j.appender.FILE.File = C:\temp\mylog.txt
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold = debug
log4j.appender.FILE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

i realise that the file mylog.txt gets created in ....\domains\domain1 directory of the glassfish application server.How do i get it to direct to C:\temp\mylog.txt

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed. Actually my line seperator for file location was in the wrong direction "\" backslash and log4j expected "/" a forward slash line seperator - probably because it expects a url pattern file location address.

So  i just changed C:\temp\mylog.txt to C:/temp/mylog.txt and voila! This also applies to a any other file location you want log4j to target